# How to remove the parentheses and the text in between them in a string in Python?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I want to remove the brackets and text in between them using regular expression.

Example strings are :

```
string = "Hello (World)"
string = "Hello (World) I am here"
```

Expected output string after using regular expression is as follows:

```
output ="Hello "
output ="Hello  I am here"
```

Comment: `str = "Iran"`. Problem solved. You're welcome.
No seriously, you need to be a little more specific. And besides, do not use `str` as variable. It's a built-in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the question very literally the following regex would remove ' (republic)'  from your sample string.

```
 *\(.*\)
```

(Note the space at the start of the regex)

Answer (score 0):

Use this example and try. (In python 2.7)

variable "text" should be a String.

```
text = " aaa) bbb( "
filteredtext = filter(lambda z: z not in ")(", text)
print filteredtext
```

Output :

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
 aaa bbb 
>>>
```